# Full bridge rectifier with an RF filter front end

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog

I'm designing a trigger circuit that only responds to a certain frequency. Essentially the plan is to have many of these circuits all buffered and running in parallel such that I can play a mixed tone into the front end and activate as many or as few threads as I want. I have simulated one such thread in LTSpice IV as shown below but try as I might the circuit either only half rectifies or doesn't filter. The example below is kinda confusing. It shows the proper frequency response (but shifted down by a few hundred dB), however this is apparently not reflected in transient analysis.

[image]

Filter response at that same node:
[image]

And as a corollary to this, how would I go about smoothing this signal with a capacitor without ruining the frequency response? Putting the filter ahead of the rectifier causes singular matrix errors at runtime.

Thanks

Comment: Have you not heard about a thing called PLL or phase locked loop?

Comment: How many discrete frequencies are you trying to detect? Switching to a digital system and using FFTs may be a better choice than this analog implementation.

Comment: There would be 14 discrete frequencies. The most important thing here is board real estate. I have limited experience with hardware design.

Comment: Both types of analysis work completely different and may not necessarily lead to the same results, especially when you use things like ideal diodes and a frequency which makes L1 conduct several kA of current

Comment: @PlasmaHH I assumed as much, but I did not notice all the current through L1. Would you recommend using the diode models instead?

Comment: @T.Welsh: absolutely. Try to be at least as realistic as possible. Add parasitics like L1 and C1 ESR too. Also the usual AC analysis in ltspice calls for AC 1 instead of AC10 voltage, don't know if that makes any differecne

Comment: @user2943160 can you recommend a very small dsp board?

Comment: @T.Welsh I don't have any recommendations, but you would also need to provide frequency and amplitude specifications to narrow potential options.

Comment: @T.Welsh: Please refrain from using expletatives / bad language on this site.

Comment: @user2943160 20-20kHz, I'm basically trying to selectively trigger led's with the sound coming out of a phone mic jack.

Comment: Consider using the LM567 tone detector. It will be much easier to accomplish your objective if you use it instead of designing your own tone detector, which is not that easy.

Comment: @mkeith This looks like exactly what I need. If I have 14 of these is it selectable enough to fit them all in the 20-20kHz range?

Comment: See Figure 12. http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/lm567.pdf Looks to be plenty selective for your application.

Comment: @user2943160 Perfect. Those cap values are way too large for my application I think from a space perspective but I can definitely work with that thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Putting the filter ahead of the rectifier causes singular matrix
>   errors at runtime.

You need a dropper resistor in series when feeding a parallel tuned circuit or you won't get any spectral shaping, just lots of current and, more than likely, that is wheat happened when your sim tried to activate - some sims don't like voltage sources in parallel with inductors.

As for putting the bridge before the parallel tuned circuit that won't work either. Yes you see a resonance up in the 100 kHz range but that is due in main to the self capacitance of the bridge rectifier and, the voltage magnification will be immense.

It looks like a peak at 503 kHz and I can confirm that the parallel combo of 100 uH and 1 nF will produce exactly that frequency: -

[image]

Feeding that tuned circuit from a small capacitance (parasitic capacitance of the diodes) will cause large voltage amplification and something that is probably not desired for your project.

Also, if you look at the transient analysis you will see that it is gradually sloping down from left to right. If you ran the analysis for long enough you would find that the average voltage would in fact be DC.

Try using the LM567 as mentioned in comments. You could of course use gyrator circuits - these are also used to emulate tuned circuits and are common place in analogue graphic equalizers and audio spectrum displays (old school designs).